# How do I do stoichiometry for 2 limiting reactants

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

> The Drano reaction produces sodium aluminate along with hydrogen gas. If a typical container of Drano weighs 500 g which is 35% by weight by weight sodium (l) hydroxide and 2.5% by weight aluminum, what volume hydrogen gas would be produced if (excess) water was added to an entire can of crystal Drano at 22 °C and 1.2 atm?

My equation:

$$\ce{4 Al + 4 Na(OH) + 12 H2O -> 4 Na[Al(OH)4] + 6 H2}$$

If my balancing correct, I am trying to get the excess for water. Would I need to do the moles left over? Or would 500 x 62.5% (2.5% and 35% added together) suffice?

If I do need to do moles left over, how do I manage with two limiting reactants?

Comment: Richard, there can be only one limiting reactant. You cannot have two by definition. The one which is present in the least amount in a stoichiometric sense, is the limiting reactant!

Comment: Besides the fact there is only one limiting reagent, the term "*moles left over*" is more applicable to the population of moles, the animals. In chemistry you probably want to use "*extensive amount*" instead.

Comment: You can simplify the equation to $\ce{2Al + 2NaOH + 6H2O -> 2Na[Al(OH)4] + 3H2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your balance equation is correct except for not simplifying it. Simplified equation should be:
 $$\ce{2Al + 2NaOH + 6H2O ⟶ 2Na[Al(OH)4] + 3H2}$$

I also think you're getting a little bit confused about your equation. You probably think reacting $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ with same mole ratio (2:2) make them two limiting reagents. If that is the case, you are absolutely wrong. As M. Farooq commented elsewhere, the one reactant, which is present in the least amount in a stoichiometric sense, is the limiting reactant. Let's see your question in hand:

The amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ in a typical container of Drano $ = \pu{500 g} \times \frac{\pu{35 g}\; \ce{NaOH}}{\pu{100 g}}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{40 g}\; \ce{NaOH}}  = \pu{4.38 mol}$

The amount of $\ce{Al}$ in a typical container of Drano $ = \pu{500 g} \times \frac{\pu{2.5 g}\; \ce{Al}}{\pu{100 g}}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{27 g}\; \ce{Al}}  = \pu{0.463 mol}$

Since $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{Al}$ react with 1:1 ratio according to the equation, $\ce{Al}$ is clearly the limiting reagent.

Hence, $\pu{0.463 mol}$ of $\ce{Al}$ reacts with $\pu{0.463 mol}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ if you added enough water to $\pu{500 g}$ of Drano container. The leftover amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ would be: $\pu{(4.38 - 0.463) mol} = \pu{3.92 mol} = \pu{3.92 mol} \times \frac{\pu{40 g}\; \ce{NaOH}}{\pu{1 mol}} = \pu{157 g}$

Now, how much water you need? You need more than $\pu{0.463 mol}\times \frac{6}{2} = \pu{1.39 mol}$ of water, which is more than $\pu{25.0 g}$ (to be excess).

**Note:** Similar calculations would appied to find out amount of $\ce{H2}$ released by the reaction.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're getting a bit confused with your equation. It's probably better to write two distinct reactions, one with $\ce{NaOH}$ and one with $\ce{Al}$.

35% of $\pu{500g}$ is $\pu{165g}$ $\ce{NaOH}$, and 2.5% of $\pu{500g}$ is $\pu{12.5g}$ $\ce{Al}$.